# pass variable from Laravel mailable class to view

Tags: laravel-5.4

I need to pass user object and a password to Laravel mailable class. I've tried so many ways, nothings seems to work. Here's my latest attempt.

Password is passed into payload properly.

**Controller**

```
Mail::to($user)
            ->queue(new EmployeeCreated($password));
```

**Mailable**

```
class EmployeeCreated extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $password;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
        $password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this
            ->subject('YOU ARE IN!')
            ->view('mail.employees.created')
            ->withPassword($password);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
You got your account. Got to {{url('/login')}}. Use e-mail as username. Your password is {{$password}}.
```

**Error message**

```
ErrorException: Undefined variable: password in /var/www/html/storage/framework/views/4c04e63464617b1ec451525800e71aa14d7540d4.php:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass them directly as type hinted constructor parameters, you're not limited on how many you can define. Set the access modifier to public:

```
public $user;

public $password;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(User $user, $password)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->password = $password;
}
```

> any public property defined on your mailable class will automatically be made available to the view.

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#view-data)

Comment: In this case I get
`ErrorException: Undefined variable: password in /var/www/html/storage/framework/views/4c04e63464617b1ec451525800e71aa14d7540d4.php:1` Just added the view

Comment: That could be an old view file, purge t he storage/framework/views directory and try again

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
class EmployeeCreated extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;


    public $user,$password;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($params)
    {
        $this->user = $params['user'];
        $this->password = $params['password'];
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this
            ->subject('YOU ARE IN!')
            ->view('mail.employees.created');
    }
}
```

Comment: The result is `ErrorException: Undefined variable: password in /var/www/html/storage/framework/views/4c04e63464617b1ec451525800e71aa14d7540d4.php:1`

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitely pass variables in Mailable lyke this:

```
...

public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.myview')->with(['variable' => $this->variable]);
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue with in the build function
Try,

```
public function build()
{
    return $this
        ->subject('YOU ARE IN!')
        ->view('mail.employees.created')
        ->with('Password',$password);
}
```